# Actualizar una imagen de carpeta local y base de datos

Tags: php, html5, mysqli, php5

quiero actualizar una imagen pero cuando trato de hacerlo me da error pero no me aparece cual fue, por favor si pueden apoyarme.

Formulario para actualizar

```html
<form action="actualizarimg.php">

<?php while($registro=$resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
<label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $registro['nombre']; ?>">
<img height="200px" src="./<?php echo $registro['ruta_imagen']; ?>">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $registro['ruta_imagen'];?>"
<label for="img">Imágen</label>
<input type="file"> <p>Subir Archivo</p> 
<label>Descripción</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $registro['descripcion']; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Actualizar">
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Actualizarimg.php

```html
<?php
include('conexion.php');
if(isset($_GET['cve_imagen'])){
    $cve_imagen=$_GET['cve_imagen'];
}
  if(isset($_GET['nombre'])){
    $nombre=$_GET['nombre'];
  }
  if(isset($_GET['descripcion'])){
    $descripcion=$_GET['descripcion'];
  }
   if(isset($_GET['ruta_imagen'])){
    $ruta_imagen=$_GET['ruta_imagen'];
   

$sql = "UPDATE imagenes SET nombre='$nombre', descripcion='$descripcion', ruta_imagen='$ruta_imagen' WHERE cve_imagen='$cve_imagen' ";
mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>;
alert ('Los datos se actualizaron exitosamente');
window.location='eliminar.php';
</script>";
 }else {
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>;
alert ('Error al actualizar los datos');
window.location='eliminar.php';
</script>";
  
 }
 $conexion->close();
 ?>
```

Comment: y cual es el error que te da?

Comment: @Alfredo solo me manda el script que coloque de error al actualizar los datos, pero no me aparece si tengo error en alguna linea del código, simplemente me manda error

Comment: manda solito es decir sin el código javascript, lo siguiente para ver cual es el error `echo("Errorcode: " . mysqli_errno($conexion));`

Comment: @Alfredo  al colocarlo asi: $sql = "UPDATE imagenes SET nombre='$nombre', descripcion='$descripcion', ruta_imagen='$ruta_imagen' WHERE cve_imagen='$cve_imagen' ";
mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
echo("Errorcode: " . mysqli_errno($conexion));
   } solo queda la pantalla en blanco y al colocarlo asi: mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
echo("Errorcode: " . mysqli_errno($conexion));
   }else{
    echo("Errorcode: " . mysqli_errno($conexion));}
 $conexion->close();
 ?>
  me aparece: Errorcode: 0

Comment: Hola, la primer línea es un include('conexion.php') estas seguro que después la variable $conexion esta definida ? Proba a hacer un print_r($conexion) antes del mysqli_query.

Comment: @JuanjooTocino si, porque al momento de escribir el $ me salen las variables que puedo usar y conexion si sale

Comment: Probaste a cambiar la consulta ? Por ejemplo, intentar hacer un SELECT * FROM imagenes, para detectar sí el problema esta en la consulta o en otra sección del código.

Comment: Si lo hice pero me sigue dando eroor :c